# Why this return a const X* const pointer within a const method?

Tags: c++, pointers

I got troubles undertanding the following error:

> Error 1   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const X<...> *const ' to 'X<...> *const '

I am trying to use a pointer to const pointer to keep track of a Node during a tree traversal:

```
bool IsValid() const
  {
    X* const* previousNode = new X*;
    return this->IsValid(previousNode);
  }

  bool IsValid(X* const* previousNode) const
  {
    ...
    if (!*previousNode)
      *previousNode = this; // Error
    ...

    return true;
  }
```

Why is **this** is a **const X* const** type and cannot be used as a ***Const** * ?

As the method is a const method, my understanding is that it protects the object itself of being modified. Then why does the compiler try to enforce the constness of a pointer to pointer returning this?

I have not been able to find an answer to this question using the search engine of stack overflow.

Thank you for your answers.

Here is the finale code I finally used if I can be a use for someone:

```
bool IsValid() const
  {
    std::unique_ptr<const BST*> previousNode = std::unique_ptr<const BST*>(new const BST*);
    *previousNode = nullptr;
    return this->IsValid(prevNode);
  }

bool IsValid(std::unique_ptr<const BST*>& previousNode) const
{
  // Recurse on left child without breaking if not failing
  if (this->leftChild &&!this->leftChild->IsValid(previousNode))
    return false;

  // First node retrieved - assign
  if (!*previousNode)
    *previousNode = this;
  // Previous data does not compare well to the current one - BST not valid
  else if (!Compare()((*previousNode)->data, this->data))
    return false;

  // Set current node
  *previousNode = this;

  // Recurse on right child
  if (this->rightChild && !this->rightChild->IsValid(previousNode))
    return false;

  return true;
}
```

Just playing with template and simple data structure.
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You pass an uninitialized pointer to `IsValid`

Comment: Thx, tried to focus on the error - corrected version:
bool IsValid() const
      {
        const BST** previousNode = new const BST*;
        *previousNode = nullptr;
        return this->IsValid(previousNode);
      }

      bool IsValid(const BST** previousNode) const

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start simple:

- a `const X*` is a pointer to a constant X
- a `const X* const` is a constant pointer to a constant X
- a `const X* const*`is a pointer to a constant pointer to a constant

Back to your problem:

- `X* const* previousNode` is a pointer to a constant pointer to an X
- so `*previousNode` is a constant pointer to an X
- but `*previousNode = ...` tries to assign something to this constant pointer.  It's not possible, the pointer is constant !

Comment: To my previous understanding *previousNode = ... means:
My non-const pointer value is a const object
I assign my non-const pointer value to a new const object 

But it seems that * const * is a non-const pointer on a const value and this pointer cannot be modified.

Then when the * const * syntax would make sens?

Comment: The thing is that there are 2 * so there is here a double indirection.  You have declared previousNode to be a non const pointer to a const pointer.  This could make sense for example if you want to protect the pointer you're pointing to (see [online demo](http://ideone.com/NKVs0Z)).  This could make sense for example if there's a risk that previousNode points to a pointer that is member of X (because isValid() is itself const and you must ensure this promise, i.e. that the member function will not accidentally modify the state of the state of the object.

Answer (score 3):

The signature of the `IsValid` method specifies (by using `const`), that `this` is a constant object, i.e. its type is `const X*`. Changing the type of `previousNode` to `const X**` should solve your problem.